# Scala UDF with collect_list task not serializable

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I am trying to use collect_list on udf field. Below is my code.
If i dont use UDF dervied field code works fine.. However using UDF derived field gives below error

```
Task not serializable: java.io.NotSerializableException: scala.runtime.LazyRef


class SparkEntry extends Serializable {
  def process(): Unit = {
    def modifyword = (file_path:String) => {file_path+"_"}
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("spp").master("local").getOrCreate()
    spark.udf.register("customudf",modifyword)
    val someData = Seq(
      Row(8, "bat"),
      Row(9, "bat"),
      Row(64, "mouse"),
      Row(9, "mouse"),
      Row(-27, "horse"),
      Row(9, "horse")
   )
  val someSchema = List(
     StructField("number", IntegerType, true),
     StructField("word", StringType, true)
  )

  val someDF = spark.createDataFrame(
    spark.sparkContext.parallelize(someData),
    StructType(someSchema)
  )
  val new_df = someDF.withColumn("new_column",callUDF("customudf",cols = col("word")))
  new_df.show()
  val grouped_df = new_df.groupBy("word").agg(collect_list(struct(col("new_column"),col("number")))).toDF("word","combined")
 grouped_df.show()
 spark.close()
```

}
}

Comment: which scala version are you using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working well for me -

```scala
   def modifyword = (file_path:String) => {file_path+"_"}
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("spp").master("local").getOrCreate()
    spark.udf.register("customudf",modifyword)
    val someData = Seq(
      Row(8, "bat"),
      Row(9, "bat"),
      Row(64, "mouse"),
      Row(9, "mouse"),
      Row(-27, "horse"),
      Row(9, "horse")
    )
    val someSchema = List(
      StructField("number", IntegerType, true),
      StructField("word", StringType, true)
    )

    val someDF = spark.createDataFrame(
      spark.sparkContext.parallelize(someData),
      StructType(someSchema)
    )
    val new_df = someDF.withColumn("new_column",callUDF("customudf",cols = col("word")))
    new_df.show()
    val grouped_df = new_df.groupBy("word").agg(collect_list(struct(col("new_column"),col("number")))).toDF("word","combined")
    grouped_df.show()

    /**
      * +------+-----+----------+
      * |number| word|new_column|
      * +------+-----+----------+
      * |     8|  bat|      bat_|
      * |     9|  bat|      bat_|
      * |    64|mouse|    mouse_|
      * |     9|mouse|    mouse_|
      * |   -27|horse|    horse_|
      * |     9|horse|    horse_|
      * +------+-----+----------+
      *
      * +-----+--------------------+
      * | word|            combined|
      * +-----+--------------------+
      * |  bat|[[bat_, 8], [bat_...|
      * |horse|[[horse_, -27], [...|
      * |mouse|[[mouse_, 64], [m...|
      * +-----+--------------------+
      */
```

Try upgrading scala version to `2.12.4`. [LazyRef](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.4/scala/runtime/LazyRef.html) is `Serializable` there

Comment: 2.12.0 let me try that. What is officially supported version for spark 3.0 any idea